# Couldn't access CentOS httpd

Tags: apache, centos

I have been using Ubuntu, just recently started to work on Centos (CentOS Linux release 7.1.1503 (Core)) running in VMplayer on my desktop (Ubuntu).

- Branch new CentOS installation.
- installed httpd (using "yum")
- for some reason, httpd didn't start automatically,  I ran "service httpd start" and it started according to "netstat -antp".

  ```
  [root@localhost ~]# netstat -antp
  Active Internet connections (servers and established)
  Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
  tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1161/sshd           
  tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1620/master         
  tcp        0      0 10.0.0.19:22            10.0.0.7:20383          ESTABLISHED 2421/sshd: root@pts 
  tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      2453/httpd          
  tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1161/sshd           
  tcp6       0      0 ::1:25                  :::*                    LISTEN      1620/master
  ```
- I can access the http server locally (`curl http://localhost` within the CentOs command line)
- when I tried access httpd from the host `curl http://172.16.13.143/`, it refused the TCP connection.  I was able to to ssh into it, it works ok for ssh `ssh root@172.16.13.143`.
- I have stopped iptables `service iptables stop`
- SELinux is turned off according to `getenforce` command.

I just need to do a quick test on the web interface but I can't. Really need some help.  Thanks.

Comment: you're listening to port 80 via ipv6 only. there is no http server on ipv4

Comment: I saw this too, not sure why. I don't have IPv6 configured on my network, why IPv6 but not IPv4.   Do you know how to get out of this?   thanks.

Comment: @MarcB, I don't think that's necessarily the case.  That can indicate a socket listening on both IPv4 and IPv6.  I just confirmed this on my system...`netstat` output looks the same, and I only use IPv4 on my network and my webserver is working :)

Comment: larsks: nope. if it was listening to ipv4, there'd be a :80 with proto `tcp`.

Comment: Nope.  Again, I've just confirmed that on my own system.

Comment: well, ain't that interesting. just checked on my own system. that's... weird.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Packages installed on RHEL/CentOS/Fedora systems aren't supposed to start any services automatically (because maybe you're not ready to expose your service to the world until after you've configured it).

Running `service httpd start` will start the service temporarily, but it won't start next time you boot.  You want `systemctl enable httpd` to enable the service to start automatically when you boot your system.

You could check if the firewall is actually disabled. Run `iptables -S` to see the current ruleset.  The default iptables configuration typically allows only `ssh` and nothing else.

**Update**

Your system is probably running `firewalld` to manage the firewall.  Try `service firewalld stop`.

You can run `systemctl disable firewalld` to prevent it from starting next time your system boots.

Comment: if it wasn't running, then why is there httpd on :::80, then?

Comment: It *is* running. It just would't run if he were to reboot.

Comment: Thanks @larsks for the answer. I enabled the service now (so next time I reboot the guest OS, httpd will be on automatically).  I got a long list of entries in `iptables -S`.  How do I disable iptables? I don't need any protection since it's development box.  Tried `service iptables stop` but didn't work (can't establish a TCP connection to httpd from my desktop).

Comment: See my update.  Your system is probably using "firewalld" to manage the local firewall.

Answer (score 2):

-- CentOS 7

add the following to '/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf'

```
Replace:
Listen 80

With:
Listen 0.0.0.0:80
```

this will disable ipv6 and enable ipv4

To check this type:

```
netstat -an | grep -i tcp | grep -i listen
```

restart apache service

```
systemctl restart httpd.service
```

Also, enable firewall to access port 80

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-service=http
firewall-cmd --reload
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you do a `iptables -L` to make sure no firewall is running?

Execute following command to make sure no other firewalls is running too

```
ps -ef
```

"80" is being listened so something is blocking your connection looks like

Answer (score 0):

In a standard installation, CentOS 7 is set to prevent traffic to Apache.

add the ports to your firewall:

for http:

```
sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=80/tcp
```

for https:

```
sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=443/tcp
```